# problem with python requests response, a different answer in the browser and another in the requirement

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I am trying to send a request to log in at https://account.efortuna.pl/login when I send the request, I get the answer: You can't because you have exceeded the login limit error code 3, in the browser, when entering the same data, an error about incorrect login data error code 2, I don't know why I get a different answer in the query.

```
import json
import time

s = requests.Session()
params = {
    'casinoname': 'efortuna.pl',
    'realMode': '1',
    'serviceType': 'GamePlay',
    'clientType': 'sportsbook',
    'clientPlatform': 'web',
    'clientVersion': '10H',
    'clientSkin': 'efortuna.pl',
    'deliveryPlatform': 'Hub2',
    'deviceType': 'other',
    'osName': 'windows',
    'osVersion': '10',
    'deviceBrowser': 'chrome',
    'languageCode': 'pl',
    #'redirectUrl': 'https://www.efortuna.pl/#requestId=',
    'messagesSupported': '1'
}

payload = {
    'username': 'myusername',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'eventOrigin': 'https://www.efortuna.pl',
    'hr': 'https://account.efortuna.pl/',
    'requestsType': 'LoginAndGetTempToken',
    'responseType': 'json'
}


s.get("https://account.efortuna.pl/login")
res = s.post('https://login.efortuna.pl/LoginAndGetTempToken.php', json=payload, data=params, verify=False)
print(res.content)
```

***RESPONSE IN BROWSER:***
errorCode: 2
playerMessage: "Invalid nickname or password. Please contact callcenter@efortuna.pl customer service for assistance"

***RESPONSE IN PYTHON REQUESTS***
errorCode: 3
playerMessage: "You cannot log in because you have timed out."

Comment: this page uses JavaScript to display elements - so it can also use JavaScript to check some values in browser or set some values in cookies. But `requests` can't run JavaScript and it is not full browser so it can be detected as bot/script/spamer and blocked.

Comment: when I check requests in Firefox (tool `DevTools`, tab `Network`) then I see it send first `GET` to `https://login.efortuna.pl/pasSetupPage.php?casino=efortuna.pl`, next `POST` with data, next again `GET` to `pasSetupPage` and next again `POST` with different data - and this can make big difference. It may have more complex system to login. Maybe you should use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can better simulate user and it runs JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know English, so I use a translator.
To log into your account with this bookmaker, you need to make 5 connections:

1.
GET from "https://www.efortuna.pl/login"
here we download cookies for the next query.

2.
GET from "https://login.efortuna.pl/pasSetupPage.php?casino=efortuna.pl"
here we also download cookies for the next query.

3.
POST from the address "https://login.efortuna.pl/Login.php?casinoname=efortuna.pl&realMode=1&clientType=sportsbook&clientPlatform=web&clientSkin=efortuna.pl&languageCode=pl&redirectUrl=https://www.efortuna.pl/#requestId=1685784741067x977367&messages Supported =1"
there is a requestId in this address but don't look at it. You can generate it yourself, or just don't change anything in this link.
In addition to the parameters passed in the URL address, we must pass the parameters in the ".send (Params)" package, and the params looks like this:

```
     Params = "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""username""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & s_username & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""password""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & s_password & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""eventOrigin""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "https://www.efortuna.pl" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""hr""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "https://www.efortuna.pl/" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""requestType""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Login" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""responseType""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "json" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundaryDVqp4YnVnJBV8KJB--"
```

From the response from the server with "ResponseText" we need to extract 3 parameters:
"userId"
"token"
"issuerSystemId"
will be needed for the URL in the next query and for the send package
We also collect a cookie for the next query

4.
POST from the address "https://login.efortuna.pl/GetTemporaryAuthenticationToken.php?casinoname=efortuna.pl&serviceType=GamePlay&systemId=" & s_issuerSystemId & "&realMode=1&clientType=sportsbook&clientPlatform=web&clientSkin=efortuna.pl&languageCode=pl&redirectUrl=https:// www .efortuna.pl/#requestId=1685784741320x763605&messagesSupported=1"
Params Bundle:

```
     Params = vbNullString
     Params = "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""userId""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & s_userId & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""token""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & s_token & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""username""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & s_username & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""eventOrigin""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "https://www.efortuna.pl" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""hr""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "https://www.efortuna.pl/" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""requestType""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "GetTemporaryAuthenticationToken" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""responseType""" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "json" & vbCrLf
     Params = Params & "------WebKitFormBoundarymokcLayrxADBba8N--"
```

Here, from the answer, we extract the "sessionToken" which will be the new login password.

5.
POST from the address "https://api.efortuna.pl/_login-desktop"
The send package is tiny this time:
Params = "username=" & s_username & "&password=" & s_New_password
Remember that sessionToken retrieved from responsetext is our "s_New_password"
We made it to the end.
Of course, in each query we must remember about the appropriate "setRequestHeader" headers.
I wish you good luck.
The above data as of today, i.e. 02.06.2023, work and will work until Fortuna changes something on the website, e.g. the URL address.
Remember that this is not access via API.